# Has Erlang R17 been released to the present date?

Tags: erlang

I have read in Joe Amstrong book Programing Erlang about maps as being a new feature in Erlang R17. I tried to look for for a R17 compiler but i couldn't find one. I even compiled the source from git hub but the version that erl shell reports is R16B3. Has R17 been released yet ? Or the book speaks about a release that will come in the future ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Erlang R17 hasn't been released yet but if you'd like to play with the new features, you can clone:

1. https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master for the latest commits of R17.
2. https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/egil/maps/eep-implementation for the new maps feature.

Maps haven't been merged/released to Github under the Master branch yet, so you'll have to build that one separately if you want to play with them.

EDIT: The Erlang team has released a few release candidates, the latest of which can be [found here](http://www.erlang.org/news/71).

Answer (score 7):

Erlang version 17 will likely be released in February 2014.

Update: in a [message to the erlang-questions mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-February/077037.html), a member of the OTP team stated they're planning to release Erlang/OTP 17.0 in March 2014.

Comment: Where we can find a roadmap for Erlang development? So we can see what is going on and what is coming next.

Comment: There's some details for the 17.0 release in this message to the erlang-patches list: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-patches/2014-February/004623.html . As for a roadmap, there really isn't one, but there is a development page at http://www.erlang.org/development/ that shows proposed updates and graduated patches.

Answer (score 1):

There is RC1 release here at https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases
you can download zip/tar and compile it or you can still clone git

Answer (score 1):

Erlang/OTP 17.0 [was released on 9th April 2014](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-April/078563.html).